# Organize Outlook email (delete messages that have been replied to)

Tags: email, outlook

Imagine the scenario where you and I converse on a subject via email.  Each time we reply to the other's email, we include all the message along with our response.  If we strictly alternate our replies, then clearly I can delete all but the last message and retain the entire conversation.

Now add several more people to this scenario and remove the strict alternation of replies such that the latest message no longer contains the entire conversation.

Is there a tool that can delete messages in the thread such that the entire thread can be reviewed with a minimum number of messages?

Or, take it to the next level and merge all responses in such a way as to preserve the entire conversation in a single message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for seems to play right into what Google was thinking for "Google Wave."  Since 99% of us don't have that, you're looking at a 3rd party add-on for Outlook.  I did a search and a few options came up.

This was at the top and seemed to be exactly what you're looking for:
http://www.easylinkmail.com/

They appear to have a demo.  Maybe you want to give it a shot and see how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

...or just use this VBA code for free and don't pay $80 for something so simple:

```
Public Sub DeleteMessagesWithRepliesWithoutAttachments()
Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myMailItem1 As MailItem
Dim myMailItem2 As MailItem
Dim lMailItem As Long
Dim deleteThisOne(10000) As Boolean
Dim cID(10000) As String
Dim atts(10000) As Integer
Dim numItems As Long
Dim ci1 As String, ci2 As String
Dim nd As Integer
On Error GoTo Err1:
Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
numItems = myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.Count
If Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then    
    For m = 1 To numItems
        Set myMailItem1 = myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items(m)
        cID(m) = myMailItem1.ConversationIndex
        atts(m) = myMailItem1.Attachments.Count
    Next
    For m = 1 To numItems - 1
        For n = m + 1 To numItems
            If Len(cID(n)) > Len(cID(m)) Then
                If Left(cID(n), Len(cID(m))) = cID(m) And atts(m) = 0 Then
                    deleteThisOne(m) = True
                End If
            ElseIf Len(cID(m)) > Len(cID(n)) Then
                If Left(cID(m), Len(cID(n))) = cID(n) And atts(n) = 0 Then
                    deleteThisOne(n) = True
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    Next
End If
For m = numItems To 1 Step -1
    If deleteThisOne(m) = True Then
        Set myMailItem1 = myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items(m)
        myMailItem1.Delete
        nd = nd + 1
    End If
Next m
MsgBox (Str(nd) + "items were deleted.")
Exit Sub

Err1:
    MsgBox ("There was an error - sorry! Try deleting non-messages from the folder first.")
End Sub
```